# Translate all text views into other language in android studio

Tags: android, azure, textview, translation

I want to translate all the text views of my android application into other languages by choosing a language from an menu. Is there any way to translate?
I heard we can translate using microsoft text translator. But don't know how to use it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! You could Azure Translator to achieve your goal.

The High level working is as follows:

[image]

Azure Translator supports 90 Languages and dialects. You could refer this to access the list of languages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/language-support

**How to use :**

First Step would be get the subscription - If you would like to try it first please use the below link :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/free/cognitive-services/

**STEP 1 :**
Create a Translator Resource : https://ms.portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesTextTranslation
[image]

**STEP 2**
Go to the resource and obtain the API Keys.

**STEP 3:**
You will have to hit the endpoint with the body,headers as specified below :

https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com

**Url Parameters :**

```
/translate?api-version=3.0&from=<SourceLang>&to=<TranslationLang>
```

**Sample Endpoint :**
If you are translating from english to german :

```
https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=de&to=it
```

**Headers :**

```
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key : <The Subscription Key you obtained>
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region : The Translator resource region which you would have provided while creating the resource.
```

**Body :**

The text to be translated should be in the below format :

```
[{
    'text': 'Hello World!'
}]
```

**Response :**

A successful response would look like below :

```
[
    {
        "translations": [
            {
                "text": "Hallo Welt!",
                "to": "de"
            },
            {
                "text": "Salve, mondo!",
                "to": "it"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Refer this [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-translator?tabs=python) for more information.